# Handle Streaming data, update a GUI, use Threads, and not miss a beat?

Tags: java, multithreading, bluetooth, streaming

This question is semi-theory, semi-how to properly code.

I am thinking about making an app in Java that will accepted streaming data, and as the data comes in, update a GUI.

So, what I am thinking of doing is just spawning off threads in Java that will:

1. collect data for X-milliseconds,
2. Take new data and update GUI with it
3. At the same time, start a new thread, collecting data for X milliseconds
4. This new thread must start off right where the first thread began

And, at the same time, all other parts of the program around going on in their own threads too.

So I need to make sure the threads don't collide, no data is lost in the mix, and I need to have an understanding of the speed limits. Say if the data is coming in at 1 Gbs vs 1 Mbs, what programming difference does that make?

The specific application includes data coming in from bluetooth and also data coming in from the Internet via an HTTPS rest API

If anyone has examples, either online or something quick and dirty right here, that'd be great. My Google searches came up dry..

Comment: For 1GB/s you need specialized hardware. I would get a better understanding of your requirements before you continue.

Comment: Why can't you just have 1 thread waiting for data, and sticking the data into some kind of buffer, and then the GUI thread reading in from the buffer, and updating accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is rather broad, but from an archtetctural point of view, I think the complexity decreases greatly if you change it to one thread reading from your device and putting the data into a buffer and one thread reading from that buffer and updating the UI. This reduces the code that needs to take care of multiple threads accessing it at the same time (idealy it reduces it to the buffer you use) and make synchronization much easier. It also decouples the fetching of the data from displaying it.

Writing the buffer can start off with using PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream, however in one of my projects it turned out not to be fast enough if you really want to provide real-time processing and display, so you might end up writing yourself a low-latency buffer class.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder if there are open source alternative classes to PipedIOStream that have the same interface? Thanks for your answer, I will play around with it.

Comment: I am wondering the same, however I am not aware of any and ended up wrapping a `byte[]` buffer myself (however, I can't make the code public).

Comment: By the way, the piped classes seem to do the trick! Haven't tested it at fast speeds but so far so good